# how can I create a procedural circuit board texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, procedural

[image]
Im curious If it's possible to create a fully procedural texture similar to this reference image using only material nodes

Comment: Designing a circuit board alone is already a complex task.Making it procedural (as 'making it with nodes') is almost impossible. However, it's possible to write a script that could make image textures like this, thought it won't be easy.

Comment: I really wish this was within the scope of this site, it is a question I would love to see an answer to. Sadly it is waaaay too broad.

Answer (score 4):

It would be VERY DIFFICULT do do this procedurally in blender using cycles nodes. This could be done in Substance Designer without as much sweat, but that still might prove a challenge.

A free, easy tool to achieve this affect is **JSplacment**.
This lightweight program excels at generating unique and customizable sci-fi patterns for use in CG programs, like blender.

To get started with JSplacment, you can download it here: https://windmillart.net/?p=jsplacement

A good tutorial for these patterns is this: https://youtu.be/ee59XU3fKFw
(He uses C4D as his main 3D program, but the way you create them for use in Blender is identical)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent step by step tutorial by Simon Thommes, starting at 1h30 here> https://youtu.be/8LD5UA_Zktg?t=5376

Comment: please don't make the answer depend on a link exclusively, if the link disappears the answer will not be useful. Try to outline the principles or workflow to make the answer stand on its own, and use the link as supporting material. To post a link only, use comments.